# Is there any dynamic neural network design which can handle increasingly changing output?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am working on a case where the dimension of labels would increasing with time. For example, at time `t`, the output is a `10` by `1` vector. Later, at time `t+5`, the output becomes a `15` by `1` vector.

In this case, for the same input, the first `10` entries of output at time `t` are the same as the ones at time `t+5`. But the rest `5` are different. The reason that the dimension of output vector is increased is that every time when we are given a new training sample, the dimension of the label of all previous training sample increases by `1`. So the expected output of the neural network is changed correspondingly.

The trivial solution is to re-train the whole model such that it can handle desired dimension of output. I know it might sound weird but I am wondering is there any smart design to build up a dynamic network such that the network can be incrementally trained by incrementally changing labels.

Comment: Will a network whose output is the size of your largest output work? Then you can simply zero out all of the irrelevant/inapplicable values. Allowing the network to have the time t as an input will help it learn the pattern.

Comment: It might work, but if we do so, it would lead to tons of parameters to train.

Comment: The output size should only affect the number of parameters in the final layer.

Comment: Have you considered sequence models, e.g. LSTM?